# How to introduce the error bars in text?

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval, reporting

I want explictly to state in my written text that the error bars in the current plot and all of the following ones represent the 95% percent of the calculated mean. However, the metric changes in the different plots.

How can I generalize this and seamlessly integrate in the text?

EDIT: per request I add this figure as an illustration. For example, how would you introduce the confidence intervals in this plot to the reader

[image]

Comment: "represent the 95% percent of the calculated mean" - something's wrong in this description.

Comment: no, not necessarily, just looking for suggestion for more experienced people @Aksakal

Comment: @Aksakal is correct, Kristof (and happens to be one of the "more experienced people" whose help you might be looking for). Although you *likely* intended to include words like "two-sided confidence limits" in your description, their absence leaves us wondering what you're actually trying to do and what exactly you mean by "the metric changes."  Could you please edit this post to clear up these ambiguities?

Comment: @whuber updated the question

Comment: Are your axes not labeled and is there no title to the graphic?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that all error bars are always 95% confidence intervals, but the *point estimates* are different metrics?  If so, I would suggest stating 'error bars reflect 95% confidence interval around point estimate', then be explicit about what metric the point estimate is in, perhaps in a legend. However, graph theory generally advises *not* to combine different metrics on the same plot unless absolutely necessary. Often, if the plot is confusing to label, it is confusing to interpret.